# Is it safer to use the 'value' or the 'textContent' property?

Tags: javascript, xss

I want to pass an email string to the [HIBP](https://haveibeenpwned.com/) API. To ensure a bit of due diligence on my side (I like Troy Hunt and don't wanna create unnecessary problems for him), I want to sanitize the user input as thoroughly as I can.

From a bit of research, I came across two methods for taking user input and passing it on to the API: [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) and [value](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_value.asp).

### Relevant code

```
var account = document.getElementById('input')

....

fetch('https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/' + account.value, {
          timeout: 1500,
          userAgent: 'test'
        })
        .then(doStuff)
```

This code uses the .value property that, from what I understand, passes a string to the fetch request. I'm wondering if textContent, which passes only... text content... as mentioned by [this guy](https://gomakethings.com/preventing-cross-site-scripting-attacks-when-using-innerhtml-in-vanilla-javascript/) is better; maybe bad guys can do more with a String?

So, with this second method, the code would look something like this.

```
var account = document.getElementById('input')
var email = account.textContent;

...

fetch('https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/' + email, {
              timeout: 1500,
              userAgent: 'test'
            })
            .then(doStuff)
```

Note: I'm new to JS and code security in general, so any information is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textContent` and `value` both return a string.

`value` only applies to form controls and returns their current value.

`textContent` applies to any element and returns the text between the start tag and the end tag.

An input doesn't have any text content (or end tag for that matter), so `textContent` is not remotely useful in your context.